# Browser extension to increase the display density on SE meta (and any other SE having the new design)

Tags: web-browser, chrome, stack-exchange

Some Stack Exchange websites have a new design, which I don't like as it wastes too much space of my screen, which decreases my productivity. Unfortunately, StackExchange provides [no option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229898/178179) to revert back to the old design. I am looking for a browser extension (preferably Chrome) to increase the display density on SE meta and any other SE (like Workplace, Money, Graphic Design) having the new design.

New design:

[image]

vs. old design:

[image]

In Gmail there is an option to have a 'compact view':

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) for things like this. It's awesome in that it lets you either modify the CSS itself (what I use), or use user-friendly buttons and knobs to configure things. It's [free in the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en).

Here's the script I use (from the awesome export function):

```
a.youarehere {
    height: 0px;
}

div.question-summary.narrow {
    line-height: 0.9em;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}

div.linked a {
    margin-bottom: 3em ;
}

.user-show-new .user-panel table td {
    padding-bottom: 0px ;
}

div.user-panel.user-panel-left {
    padding-top: 0px ;
}

div.subheader {
    padding: 0px;
}

a.site-hyperlink {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

td.icon-cell {
    padding-top: 5px ;
}

div.user-show-new {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#tabs a:hover {
    height: 0px;
}
```

And here are my results:

#### Before:

[image]

#### After:

[image]

#### Before:

[image]

#### After:

[image]

There are obviously some places where the custom CSS could use some work, but I think it looks rather good for fifteen minutes' work. Feel free to [fork the Gist](https://gist.github.com/Undo1/11098052) if you'd like to contribute!

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome, extensions like **Stylish** and **Stylist** exist for the purpose. This is also possible in Firefox.

It works by applying your own custom CSS when you visit defined page. This way you can make changes to any website.

The **Stylish** extension also has a public directory for sharing such stylesheets for various websites at [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org).

You can even [re-style StackOverflow to dark colors](http://userstyles.org/styles/browse/stackoverflow).

[Read more >>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30295/how-to-permanently-add-css-to-some-pages-using-firefox)